# sending a larg string on socket by Apache Netty,but gets incomplete string in client side

Tags: sockets, tcp, netty

I am sending a string with 2000 character on TCP socket by netty, both side of client and server,I set this pipeline :

```
socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(
                        new StringEncoder(),
                        new StringDecoder(),
                        new LineBasedFrameDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE),
                        myHandler);
```

on server side, I have a ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.

```
 @Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
                     // some code
                     ctx.writeAndFlush(line);
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER)
            .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
}
```

on client side I have a SimpleChannelInboundHandler. but I get my string incomplete. why !? How can I solve that?

```
  protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, Object msg) throws Exception {//msg is incomplete}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found solution.
new LineBasedFrameDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE) is nonsense. because maximum of characters in each String in java is 65536, so try new LineBasedFrameDecoder(65536) or any size you need.
In server side each msg should end with \n or \r\n. so for example if you read a line from a text file you need add \n in the end of that.

Comment: 65535 actually.

Comment: 65535 actually, but it's irrelevant, as there is no single `String` involved. The problem was the missing line terminator.